# How can I flash the latest messages given by users, among multiple users, using PHP, just like Twitter tweets works?

Tags: php, streaming

How can I flash the latest messages given by users, among multiple users, using PHP, just like Twitter tweets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use AJAX for that one and shown in a common page.

Algo:

1. Send a request to the server to check if there are any updates in (for example) your message_table.
2. If there is, return the newly added message. Send a NONE message if none and return to step 1.

You can also try reading [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) which is an optimized way to do this. Or if not, you can do it with the traditional ajax polling.

Comment: thanx SHeek for reply could just give me some live examples fo implementation of Comet, which similar to my task?

Comment: @OM The You'll have to start reading and learning a bit yourself. There are some good sites linked to at the end of that Wikipedia article, even with some code. Don't expect to get copy-n-pastable answers to broad one-sentence questions.

Comment: @deceze please be kind in your words.. I Have not ask for the "copy-n-pastable answers to broad one-sentence questions" I Have asked for the live demo examples like my task.. for your kind information I wont be able to grab "PHP CODE FROM THE DESIRED DEMO". Before criticinzing on pun\blic forum think 1000 times.. Your words are humiliating..

Comment: @OM The Please also think about your words. Many of your questions and requests show very little desire for learning by yourself, which is kind of expected of users of this site and is a necessary skill for programmers in general. Your questions are often very short and ask for a lot of code or explanation in return. This, too, is not very polite. It gives the impression that you want people to do your work for you. I realize that half of this may be a culture/language barrier problem; that therefore my criticism has also hit you harder than intended.

Comment: @guys, no need to argue. @OM, comet is actually a concept and pasting a functioning demo here would be sizable. I suggest reading about it in wikipedia or look for any blogged concepts about it. :)

Comment: @deceze I Did learnt it.. Its not about culture My friend.. DO NOT DISCRIMINATE May be you are right of what you feel by my questions you could have put it in better way... which could have inspired me of doing what you feel I should rather than responding to your harsh words.. Anyways thanx for pointing me.. I am here to learn BTW not for making other to do my task.. If this is that easy then I could be a GOOD MANAGER.. :)

Comment: @OM I did not mean this in any discriminatory way. I myself am living in a very different culture than I grew up in, so I'm the last person that would discriminate against anybody on a cultural basis. I really simply mean that you may take criticism differently and ask questions differently because of your cultural background. This happens and that's perfectly alright. If you don't think that culture plays any role in this, ignore my remark. I know I can be harsh sometimes, but I'm not doing it to attack or belittle you. I just want you to ask better questions, that's all.